# Como realizar una clave foranea en SQlite.net desde c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, sqlite3

Hola amigos estoy trabajando en un proyecto de c# soy nuevo en esto y no encuentro la forma para declarar una foranea desde una clase con codigo de c# 
aclaro que estoy usando el modelo MVC pero 
les proporciono una de mis clases

```
 class producto
{
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [SQLite.NotNull]
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string tipo { get; set; }
    public int numero { get; set; }
    [SQLite.NotNull]
    public string porcion { get; set; }
    //Si yo quiero una foranea como la declaro crei que seria asi
    // [SQLite.ForeignKey] 



}
```

}

Les agradesco si alguien me puede orientar

Comment: que libreria usas para definir los atributos de SqLite ? usas esta libreria https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes declarar llaves foráneas con SQLite por defecto, sin embargo existe una extensión para SQLite llamada [SQLite Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions), que te permite utilizar este tipo de relaciones del siguiente modo:

```
[ForeignKey(typeof(Stock))]
public int StockId { get; set; }
public DateTime Time { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Donde "Stock" es el nombre de la tabla que contiene la llave primaria, y el campo "StockId" vendría a ser el campo de la llave foránea.

Espero te sirva de ayuda, nos comentas.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo @Adolfo F. Ibarra Landeo